# How to make floating div's in jquery or bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, floating

Can someone please show me how to make a floating div which moves when I scroll my mouse up and down in bootstrap or jquery? I've a lengthy page in which one div needs to be visible even if I scroll down.

Comment: `#your_element { position: fixed; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you make the element you want to constantly be visible `position: fixed;`, it will not move when the page does.